# Write Mongoose documents to csv file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose, export-to-csv

I have some documents in a MongoDB database.

I want to export print these documents as a csv file.

Some of the documents have nested objects, so I guess I have to manipulate them first.

So a document could be

```
{
  name: {
    english: "English Name",
    spanish: "Spanish name"
  },
  subdocuments: [
    {
      quantity: 100,
      price: 20
    },
    {
      quantity: 200,
      price: 30
    },
  ]
}
```

I guess the best solution would be to print this object as two rows:

```
English Name, Spanish Name, Quantity, Price
===========================================
English Name, Spanish Name, 100, 20
English Name, Spanish Name, 200, 30
```

So how can I do this? Is it best to use a write-to-csv Node.js package?

I think I need to retrieve the documents with

```
const rows = [];
Collection.find({}).then(docs => {
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    doc.subdocuments.forEach(subdocument => {
      rows.push({ 'English Name': doc.name.english, 'Spanish Name': doc.name.spanish, quantity: subdocument.quantity, price: subdocument.price });
    });
  });
});
```

But with this approach, I will only get a row if the document contains subdocuments, so I am also interested in a single row if `subdocuments` array is empty - just with quantity and price columns empty.

When I have this array of objects, I want to write it to a csv file, which might be very simple, so I guess it's best to just do something like

```
var csv = '';

// headers
csv += 'English Name, Spanish Name, Quantity, Price\n';

rows.forEach(row => {
  csv += row['Spanish Name'] + ', ' + row['English Name'] + ', ' + row.quantity + ', ' + row.price + '\n';
});
```

But is this really the right approach? And how can I make sure the user downloads it as a csv file? The text can also include special characters (e.g. ö, ä, etc.). I am using Express in Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Problem with empty subdocuments you can solve by changing your code to:

```
const rows = [];
Collection.find({}).then(docs => {
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    if(doc.subdocuments.length === 0)
        rows.push({ 'English Name': doc.name.english, 'Spanish Name': doc.name.spanish, quantity: 0, price: 0 });
    doc.subdocuments.forEach(subdocument => {
      rows.push({ 'English Name': doc.name.english, 'Spanish Name': doc.name.spanish, quantity: subdocument.quantity, price: subdocument.price });
    });
  });
});
```

Later you can convert it to csv using for example [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv)